# Как запаковать несколько файлов в один zip архив на лету?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, zip, zipfile

Есть фрейм данных, допустим на 1 млн строк. Нужно сохранить результат в один zip архив, содержащий 100 csv файлов, в каждом по 10к строк.

Реализовал такую функцию, которая делит фрейм на эти файлы, но архивирует каждый отдельно:

```
def result_writer(data):
    chunk_size = 10000 #по сколько строк делить файл
    counter = 0
    for chunk in pd.read_csv(data, chunksize=chunk_size):
        counter = counter + 1
        chunk.to_csv(f'file_{str(counter)}.csv.gz',compression='gzip',index=False)
```

Как подправить, чтобы у меня получился один zip архив, а не сто?

Comment: вам нужен `.zip` или `.gz` (GNU zip) ?

Comment: @MaxU лучше zip, но не принципиально

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

[Сам модуль Pandas поддерживает только архивы, содержащие **единственный** файл внутри.](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

> If using `zip`, the ZIP file must contain only one data file to be
> read in. Set to None for no decompression.

В вашем случае можно воспользоваться модулями `io` и `zipfile`, но опять же стандартный `pd.read_csv()` не сможет прочитать такой файл.

Вот рабочий пример:

```
import io
import zipfile


data_filename = "test.csv"
chunk_size = 10000
counter = 0

with zipfile.ZipFile("data.zip", "a", zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zp:
    for chunk in pd.read_csv(data_filename, chunksize=chunk_size):
         counter += 1
         f = io.StringIO(chunk.to_csv(index=False))
         zp.writestr(f'file_{counter:03d}.csv', f.getvalue())
         f.close()
```